# Quickblox, chat room does not sends push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

I created a chat room in Quickblox, when i sends message to chatroom its offline users does not get any push notification.

To send message :

```
[[QBChat instance] sendMessage:@"Hey! Did you see last Liverpool match?" toRoom:liverpoolFansRoom];
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong or its not enabled on Quickbolx server to sends notification on chatroom's offline users.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Push messages does not sends automatically. If you know your recipient user's ID you can send push message manually - you should call method provided below:

```
[QBMessages TSendPushWithText:@"text"
toUsers:(int)userId
delegate:nil];
```

Comment: For group chat do i need to send push to all users weather  they are online or offline.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** :

You can send push notifications for all user connected with the dialog using following code:

```
var payload = [String:String]()
payload["message"] = message.text!
payload["dialog_id"] = self.dialog.id!

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let message = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    var opponentIDs: [String] = []
        for userId in self.dialog.occupantIDs! {
            // Discard currently logged in user
            if userId.uintValue != _user.id {
                opponentIDs.append(String(describing: userId))
            }
        }    
        let event = QBMEvent()
        event.message = message
        event.usersIDs = opponentIDs.joined(separator: ",")
        event.notificationType = QBMNotificationType.push
        event.type = QBMEventType.oneShot

        QBRequest.createEvent(event, successBlock: { (response, arrEvents) in
            kprint(items: event.name ?? "")
        }, errorBlock: { (errRes) in
                kprint(items: errRes.error?.description ?? "")
            })    
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```